# Rails mailer argument error from separate module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

In my app, I have a support page where on can send an email for support :P. Also in my app, I have a module for making requests

```rb
#lib/requester.rb
module Requester

  def post(rel_url, body, token = nil, headers = {})
    request(:post, rel_url, body, token, headers)
  end

  def request(method, rel_url, body = nil, token = nil, additional_headers = {})
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    headers[:Authorization] = "Bearer #{token}" if token
    headers.merge!(additional_headers) unless additional_headers.empty?

    HTTParty.send(method.to_sym, "#{base_url}#{rel_url}", headers: headers, body: body)
  end
end
```

My mailer is throwing an error here, but the thing is, it doesn't call/include/invoke the module in anyway. Here is how the mailer is called in the controller:

```rb
  def send_tech_support_email
    support_mailer.send_tech_support_email.deliver_later
  end

  def support_mailer
    SupportMailer
      .with(
        user: current_api_user_profile,
        description: notify_params[:description].to_s
      )
  end
```

And there is the mailer method

```rb
  def send_tech_support_email
    defaults

    mail(
      to: ENV['SUPPORT_TECH_EMAIL'],
      subject: 'Support Request',
      template_name: 'send_support_email'
    )
  end
```

As you can see, it does not call any of the methods in the requester module. Anyone have a clue as to what could be causing this? The error is

`wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..5)\n/path/to/local_app/lib/requester.rb:25:in 'request'`

Using `delayed_job` for the queue adapter. Also when using `deliver_now` it works without issue. It's only when sending in the background that the error pops up and prevents the email from being sent

Comment: What are you calling and what is the full backtrace from the error?  You should be able to work your way backward to what is calling that `request` method.

Comment: I'm calling the mailer method `send_tech_support_email `.  the next line in the trace is `lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-5.2.5/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb:20:in 'assign_controller'`. Also, when I use deliver_now, it works fine. Nowhere in the flow does the request method get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your controller may be including your `Requester` module.  That will override a core Rails method called `request`.  Based on the backtrace, the failure is coming out of [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb#L20):

```rb
# ActionView::Helpers::ControllerHelper
@_request = controller.request if controller.respond_to?(:request)
```

[`request`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-and-response-objects) is a special method available to controllers.  You'll need to either not include `Requester` in your controller, rename your `request` method, or move your `request` method to where you can call it without including it within the controller itself.

You may want to check what your controller inherits from.  If it's something like `ApplicationController`, maybe that is including `Requester`.

If you temporarily put this code in your controller action it will show all the ancestor classes that include the module:

```rb
raise self.class.ancestors.select { |ancestor| ancestor.include?(Requester) }.map(&:name).join(', ')
```

Comment: This was exactly it! Thanks so much, I don't think I would've ever found this